# PHP write array of bytes to a tcp stream

Tags: php, arrays

I am trying to write some binary data (in an array of unsigned chars) to a tcp stream, the data looks like this:

```
array(44) {
  [0]=>int(0)
  [1]=>int(44)
  [2]=>int(10)
  [3]=>int(0)
  [4]=>int(5)
  [5]=>int(108)
  [6]=>int(111)
  [7]=>int(103)
  ...
```

And what I would like to get to is a string holding the same binary bytes, that I can throw into fwrite() to send these bytes down a TCP connection.

Everything I have tried using join etc, so far has ended up with the ascii equivalent (eg the first byte ends up as 0x30 , an ascii '0', instead of 0x00)

What I need to end up with is binary data in the string ie 0x00, 0x2C, 0x0A  not an ascii representation of the data.

Ideas?

Answer (score 0):

You just can use the function "decbin()" to convert your integer into a binary format.

After this you can send the binary code to your TCP connection.

Here is a code example:

```
<?php
$numbers = array(
       0 => "0",
       1 => "1",
       2 => "2"
       );

$bin = decbin($numbers[1]);
$bin = substr("00000000",0,8 - strlen($bin)) . $bin;

echo $bin;
?>
```

Output is 00000001 for Number 1.

Comment: Unfortunately, that is not the answer. That produces a string representation of a binary number, consisting of 8 bytes, containing either the binary number 0x30 for 0 or 0x31 for 1